# How can I maximize the sound of the notifications on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, notifications

I have set the Settings > Sounds & Haptics > Ringer and Alerts > volume slider to the maximum level:

<sup>Click for full size</sup>
[image]

However, the sound level of the notifications is still quite low. For example, it is much lower than the sound level of the preview sound in the Ringer and Alerts menu, or the sound level of the notifications on my Google Pixel 6.

How can I maximize the sound of the notifications on my iPhone?

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the edit but could you please use [HTML tags](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2680/12202) to avoid reducing the image quality? thanks!

Comment: The entire idea is to reduce data size, rather than use html to just make it appear smaller. Anyone who needs full size can click through. I disagree with the proposal in your link & so does the majority on main meta.